# General and specific onclick event handler needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an onclick event handler for the whole document:

```
document.onclick = function(objEvt){
    alert("document click");
}
```

For some elements, I need a specific onclick event handler, too:

```
$(divElementObj).click( function() {
    alert("div click");
});
```

I always only get the output of the document event handler. What must I do to see both alerts?

Comment: Events bubble, it's one of the main principles behind javascript events in a browser enviroment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stopPropagation:

```
$(divElementObj).click( function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
    alert("div click");
});
```

---

[What does the stopPropagation do?](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: Congrats @C-link for acheiving 10K